# How do I create a file of a hash of everything (individually) in a directory tree?

Tags: hash, md5

I have several **pdf**, **jpg**, **png** files inside an alphabetical directory tree.  How do I produce a file of the **hash** of each individual file?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this.. 
which OS are you using? 
What is the exact format to save the results?

Here is an example of a simple bash (version 4) script in Linux that gives you the hash followed by the file name on separate lines, including all sub-directories.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
FILES=**
OUTPUT=output.txt
for f in $FILES
do
  md5sum $f >> $OUTPUT
done
```

Comment: Just hash and file name text format.  On linux.  How about dateToday fileName hash neatly column separated?